# Log4J 2 failing to configure

Tags: log4j, slf4j, log4j2, jetty-9

I have a Jetty 9 based application that I inherited. I am trying to put in some logging functionality. I am using slf4j with log4j2. I have added the appropriate jars for this using Maven:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Unfortunately, the application keeps failing to find the log4j2.xml file:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

I have placed copies of that XML file in the webapps folder, the main folder under my server, and in the folder where the libraries are -- all places on the web application's classpath. The application still doesn't find it.

Can someone please advise on how I can make this application find the XML file?

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at the Log4j2 [manual page for web applications](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html). 
By default Log4j2 looks in the WEB-INF folder of your web application.

Comment: That is the problem: I *did* read that documentation (I always do before asking questions in Stack Overflow). I put the appropriate "params" as instructed and put a copy of the XML file in WEB-INF. I still get the error message. The documentation is erroneous. That is why I posted here in the first place...

Comment: You're right, WEB-INF looks wrong. Have you tried WEB-INF/classes?